# get angle between sun and face normals

Tags: python, scripting, lighting, faces, fluid-simulation

I am trying to use python to compute the solar intensity on each face. for that I need to compute the angle between sun radiation and face normal. This is my code. it gives the correct angle or some faces but not for all faces.

[image]

```
import bpy
import math
import mathutils

# Define the rotation angle in radians (45 degrees converted)
angle = math.radians(45)

# Create a new sun lamp data block
sun_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name="SunLamp", type='SUN')

# Create a new object based on the sun lamp data
sun_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Sun", object_data=sun_data)

sun_object = bpy.data.objects['Sun']
sun_object.data.energy = 1368

# Add the sun object to the scene collection
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(sun_object)

# Create a new cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0, 0, 0))  # Location at origin

# Access the cube object
cube = bpy.context.object

# Scale the cube on the y-axis by 2
cube.scale = (1, 2, 1)


cube.rotation_mode='AXIS_ANGLE'
cube.rotation_axis_angle[0] = math.radians(90) 

sun_object.rotation_mode='AXIS_ANGLE'
sun_object.rotation_axis_angle[0] = math.radians(45) 

# Center the cube at the origin (optional)
# cube.location = (0, 0, 0)

for face in cube.data.polygons:
    normal_world = face.normal.copy()  # Get face normal in object space
    # normal_world = cube.matrix_world @ normal_world  # Transform to world space
    print(f"Face Normal (World Space): {normal_world}", f"Face Normal: {face.normal.copy()}")
    angle = math.degrees(normal_world.rotation_difference(Vector((0,0,1))).rotation_difference(sun_object.matrix_world.to_quaternion()).angle)
    print(angle, math.cos(math.radians(angle)), math.cos(math.radians(angle))*sun_object.data.energy)
```